# How to collaspe padding of each cell in table?

Tags: html, css

Pure CSS is used in HTML Code; When table is generated by default cells have much spacing in them.

Following is HTML for the same:

```
<table class="pure-table fullWidth">
 <tbody>
  <tr class="pure-table-odd">
   <td>
    <label class="boldText">Bank</label>
   </td>
   <td>
    <label class="boldText">Japha Bank</label>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Following is layout information taken from firebug:

```
Margin = 0 0 0 0  (West North East South)
Border = 0 0 0 0   
Padding = 14 7 14 7
Size: 111 * 29

box-sizing:content-box
position:static
Z:auto
```

Following is present output; which should n

[image]

In above Image, the cells are quite large then required in specification.

How to remove all padding between cell text and cell border so that they stick together?

Comment: What happens if you set `td {padding:0px} `?

Comment: Nothing happens. When given to table

Comment: But when i write <td style="padding:0 0 0 0">. Then text comes to left border but whole cell does not get small.

Comment: OK try setting this CSS for table `table{border-collapse: collapse} td{padding:0px}`

Comment: Well, question is what is content of `label` and `table` class... btw, if You try `<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">` and still have problem, then is something about those classes.

Comment: @TheUnknown
But the above will set to whole project. Can i do it for this particular table only?

Comment: @Nelek 
No it does not work

Comment: Can You provide css for `pure-table`, `fullWidth`, `pure-table-odd` and `boldText` in Your question.

Comment: @nelek
pure-table and pure-table-odd are Pure CSS classes ( http://purecss.io/ ). fullWidth is just 100% width and boldText is just font-weight:bold.

Comment: Yeah... I just look into `pure-min.css` and there is class `.pure-table td,.pure-table th{border-left:1px solid #cbcbcb;border-width:0 0 0 1px;font-size:inherit;margin:0;overflow:visible;padding:.5em 1em}`... like You can see, there is `padding` of `.5em` and `1em`.

Comment: Yea you can do it for a particular table by adding a `class` or `id` for the table and specify rules in those. Or use inline css

Comment: Yes, set some `id` for table (example `id="myTable"`) and in css add `#myTable: padding:0;` ... padding will be overridden.

Answer (score 1):

Here, extracted css from `pure-min.js` which You use.
Only add `id` for Your table and in css override what You need for `td`

There is example for two tables (first modified with `id` for table, second not modified)

```css
#myTable td {padding-top:0; padding-bottom:0;} 
/*there You can set everything what You need for table td's, or just set padding:0 */

.pure-table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;empty-cells:show;border:1px solid #cbcbcb}
.pure-table caption{color:#000;font:italic 85%/1 arial,sans-serif;padding:1em 0;text-align:center}
.pure-table td,.pure-table th{border-left:1px solid #cbcbcb;border-width:0 0 0 1px;font-size:inherit;margin:0;overflow:visible;padding:.5em 1em}
```

```html
<table class="pure-table fullWidth" id="myTable">
 <tbody>
  <tr class="pure-table-odd">
   <td>
    <label class="boldText">Bank</label>
   </td>
   <td>
    <label class="boldText">Japha Bank</label>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>

<br><br>

<table class="pure-table fullWidth">
 <tbody>
  <tr class="pure-table-odd">
   <td>
    <label class="boldText">Bank</label>
   </td>
   <td>
    <label class="boldText">Japha Bank</label>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

**UPDATE :** (based on user comment *we are not suppose to use ID's in CSS for applying it* ... insted `id` there is new `.myTable`) :

```css
.myTable td {padding-top:0px !important; padding-bottom:0px !important;} 
/*there You can set everything what You need for table td's, or just set padding:0 */

.pure-table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;empty-cells:show;border:1px solid #cbcbcb}
.pure-table caption{color:#000;font:italic 85%/1 arial,sans-serif;padding:1em 0;text-align:center}
.pure-table td,.pure-table th{border-left:1px solid #cbcbcb;border-width:0 0 0 1px;font-size:inherit;margin:0;overflow:visible;padding:.5em 1em}
```

```html
<table class="pure-table fullWidth myTable">
 <tbody>
  <tr class="pure-table-odd">
   <td>
    <label class="boldText">Bank</label>
   </td>
   <td>
    <label class="boldText">Japha Bank</label>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>

<br><br>

<table class="pure-table fullWidth">
 <tbody>
  <tr class="pure-table-odd">
   <td>
    <label class="boldText">Bank</label>
   </td>
   <td>
    <label class="boldText">Japha Bank</label>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Just saw project, as per its standards we are not suppose to use ID's in CSS for applying it. Can we do above using Class on Table and applying to each td of that class

Comment: update Your question and mention that. because others. there was many suggestion using id.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the nowrap Attribute

[Read more here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_nowrap.asp)

And [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_td_nowrap)

Comment: it sound like there is some other css that affects the code. add !important, to avoid other css, like this : td{padding:0px !important}

Comment: Always try and avoid using `!important` instead assign an `id` to the table and apply CSS to id